# How to handle LifeCycle issues when using callbacks

Tags: android

My app makes frequent use of the following pattern:

- User clicks button
- API request is fired
- response is parsed
- Callback returns data Data is updated in view.

However, due to the nature of the API these callbacks can take some time and I find that I can easily crash the app if I navigate around the app at a high pace. Mostly this is caused by NullPointerExceptions related to the fact that the activity and/or fragment no longer exists. My question is what the best practice is when dealing with these issues. Should I just check for null values everywhere? I've read somewhere that you should just avoid using callbacks to update the UI at all but I'm not sure what the alternative is.

Thank you all!

Comment: How are you making your api calls at the moment? Are you using a library?

Comment: Data downloaded thru the API is stored locally after being downloaded?

Comment: Agree with @W0rmH0le Answer!

Comment: No, data is not stored locally. I'm using Volley for the network requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Fragment you can check by `isAdded()`

```
 public void onResponse(){
    if(isAdded()){
        // Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

In activity `isFinishing()`

```
public void onResponse(){
    if(!isFinishing()){
        // Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering whether this was the way to go. It just seems... cumbersome... having to put that check in everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Let me share how I did in one of my apps.

- I created a class which extends `Application` and that class is responsible to initiate a database. It is Singleton Static database and everytime I need to do something, I call `db.getInstance().doSomething()`
- When any API method is called, I start an AssyncTask which store the data on database after completed (in case of failure, nothing is saved).
- When Database is updated, it sends a `LocalBroadcast`. You can send broadcasts to notify the error (which stops the Refresh animation and show a error message, for example).
- Each activity has a `BroadcastReceiver` which register to receive the local broadcast sent by Database. I register during `onStart()` and de-register during `onStop()`. Each activity register to proper event (since you can create multiples intents and actions... This way, your activity receives only the desired intent and not every single broadcast of your app.
- This way, when the activity is opened, it checks the data from database and if any content change, it receives a broadcast notification and take proper actions.
- When the activity is closed, it no longer receive broadcast.. However, the updated data will be there on database after download is completed.
- You must handle situations where some API call was already started to avoid calling twice (at least, until first call of same method finishes etc)..

You can also use `ContentObserver` to monitor some database etc.

This is one way to handle. It may work or not for you case etc... Just sharing since it may help you

Comment: This reminds me of how I used to do things back in the days before MVP and its peers became popular. Using LocalBroadcasts doesnt really fit my MVP architecture.

Comment: Personally, I don't like MVP because of that.. everything is a call back.. Using Broadcasts, you register your activity to receive and de-register when you need.. Don't need to care about if activity/fragment is still visible etc... But using MVP, you have no left option than add kind of checking (isFinishing() / isAdded() / isVisible() / etc)